# Grouping Response Data

Tags: api, rest, go, grouping, response

I am trying to get data from my database but when I show and make it become api response, I have some problem for grouping it based on productid.

I have response data that created based on golang like this:

```
[
            {
                "product_id": "1",
                "product_name": "Cardigan",
                "pitems": [
                    {
                        "id": "625ad1bc-66c5-440e-a527-d029d401ec2b",
                        "name": "Box",
                        "qty": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "625ad1bc-66c6-440e-a527-d029d401ec2b",
                        "name": "test items1",
                        "qty": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "625ad1bc-66c7-440e-a527-d029d401ec2b",
                        "name": "test items2",
                        "qty": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "625ad1bc-66c8-440e-a527-d029d401ec2b",
                        "name": "test items3",
                        "qty": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "product_id": "2",
                "product_name": "Polo",
                "product_sku": "P01",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": "625ad1bc-66c5-440e-a527-d029d401ec2b",
                        "name": "Box",
                        "qty": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "625ad1bc-66c6-440e-a527-d029d401ec2b",
                        "name": "test items1",
                        "qty": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "625ad1bc-66c7-440e-a527-d029d401ec2b",
                        "name": "test items2",
                        "qty": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "625ad1bc-66c8-440e-a527-d029d401ec2b",
                        "name": "test items3",
                        "qty": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

But This response is not my expected result, my expected result is like:

```
[
            {
                "product_id": "1",
                "product_name": "Cardigan",
                "pitems": [
                    {
                        "id": "625ad1bc-66c5-440e-a527-d029d401ec2b",
                        "name": "Box",
                        "qty": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "625ad1bc-66c6-440e-a527-d029d401ec2b",
                        "name": "test items1",
                        "qty": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "625ad1bc-66c7-440e-a527-d029d401ec2b",
                        "name": "test items2",
                        "qty": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "product_id": "2",
                "product_name": "Polo",
                "product_sku": "P01",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": "625ad1bc-66c8-440e-a527-d029d401ec2b",
                        "name": "test items3",
                        "qty": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Can Anyone help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean to show detailed data?

the easy way is:

create 2 func like this:

```
func detail(id int)(result model.Struct) 
{  return result   }

func product()(result model.Struct_Result) {

 for data.Next() {  

 // call func detail   

 data.Scan(&id, &product)   

 detailResult := detail(id) 
   
 // then put together with struct and mix append ()

  outputLoop := model.Result{
  "product_id": id,
  "pitems": [
               {
                "id": detailResult.id,
                "name": detailResult.name,
                "qty": detailResult.qty
               },
            ]
  }

    result = append(result,outputLoop) 

  }
return result
 }
```